# Can pytest throw stderr on failure?

Tags: python, pytest, stderr

I'm running pytest through a Python script, and I want it to know if the pytest has failed. The intuitive way for me would be to catch any stderr on pytest's exit, but I just can't seem to find a way to do it. Any tips?

My tests look like this:

```
def test_2():
  object = Object()
  object.func()
  assert object.property == expected_value
```

The tests are called like this:

```
pytest.main([path_to_test, "-s"])
```

I want to know whether even a single assert has failed, and do something about it, maybe like so:

```
err = io.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stderr(err):
  pytest.main([path_to_test, "-s"])
```

So basically I want pytest to throw anything in stderr when it's done if any test has failed.

A solution I've found is to replace asserts with a function that immediately throws an error, but then not all tests are ran.

Edit:
OK, I just had another idea, which looks like this:

```
def assert_test(test_case):
  if not test_case:
      sys.stderr.write("failure")
  assert test_case
```

I guess I found something that works for me, but I still find it weird that there's no built-in or prettier solution...

Edit edit:
OK, so that solution messes up the logging. I've resorted to monkey patching the assert... IDK if that's a great idea.

```
class AssertionError():
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    sys.stderr.write("failure")
    raise builtins.AssertionError
```

Now the calling script is aware if there was a failure.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about what you are asking. Have you considered using a logger inside your tests, this way you could redirect your messages to stdout or stderr depending on the log level. If you are not interested in that, you can just change your print statements to ```sys.stderr.write(...)```?

Comment: I've updated the question, does this help?

Comment: Yes I understood more clearly your problem. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pytest.main()` returns the exit code as a result, so if you're looking for a pass/fail on the entire run you can check the return value, just like you would in a shell script. It is very coarsely-grained, however, it is just the one pass/fail value for the entire test run.

According to the docs, [the following exit codes are defined](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#possible-exit-codes):

> - Exit code 0:    All tests were collected and passed successfully
> - Exit code 1:    Tests were collected and run but some of the tests failed
> - Exit code 2:    Test execution was interrupted by the user
> - Exit code 3:    Internal error happened while executing tests
> - Exit code 4:    pytest command line usage error
> - Exit code 5:    No tests were collected

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive and proper way to go to know if a test has failed would be a failed assertion in the code. This will be caught by pytest which will print the captured messages for this test.

To go further, there are multiple ways to achieve what you want. First, note that `pytest` has a capturing mechanism that captures everything that was directed to stdout or stderr. In order to disable is mechanism you can provide pytest with the `-s` argument. Then you can write your messages to stderr by calling `sys.stderr.write(...)` or you can make or more advanced use of a logger. You can also supply other capture methods like file descriptors and check their content. But again, this should not be the way to probe if a test passed.

After your last edit I think I understood more clearly what you are trying to do. For a prettier solution you can try to use `pytest.raises` which will raise an exception at pytest level. This will affect the return code of the pytest program. What you have to do then is check if the return value is different than 1 to check if there was an error.

Comment: I've tried using -s, but no stderr was thrown, just stdout, even when an assert has failed.

Comment: Thanks, did you mean pytest.raises? Because using that seems to stop the run, as opposed to assertion errors which pytest seems to know how to "digest". I want the run to go on, I was just looking for a channel to alert if a test has failed.

Comment: Have you looked at this feed then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215850/py-test-teardown-see-if-the-test-failed-and-print-subprocess-output